# Custom tooltips in Highcharts diagrams

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

Is there any way to make **completely** custom tooltips in Highcharts diagrams? Not just with different data, or with coloured border, but to make it look different (for example, like a bubble with picture in it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

....

```
tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() { 
                    return 'here the html code';
                }
            },
```

Comment: @Miguel: Is it possible to add  a button and trigger it using ng-click.Any input will be very helpful...

Comment: Have you tried to return the button as html with the ng-click tag in it? Doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Using the options/api you can only configure such things as border properties and colors (see [tooltip options](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip)). So without editing the source or going outside the api, no it is not possible.

Internally the tooltip consists of a SVG group that contains a rectangle with a text inside. If you want to edit the source, have a look in the Chart.js file around [line 1898](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/parts/Chart.js#L1898).

Comment: This is outdated, see response from Miguel

Comment: It sure is, its almost two years old.

Answer (score 4):

I've used another post from a different thread, and merged the useHTML section along with it to add an image as part of each tool tip at the top. I chose BBC logo at the top..

so, you can use

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() { 
        // Use regular html syntax
        s = '<img src="" />' + 
        return s;
    }
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YXetx/41/)