# See Highcharts tooltip under a image

Tags: highcharts

I use renderer.image to superimpose a foreground image on a chart:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                renderForegroundImage(this);
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [110, 130, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 225.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 105.6, 136]
    }]
}

);

function renderForegroundImage(chart) {

    chart.renderer.image('http://i57.tinypic.com/2m2w9iq.png', chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop, chart.plotWidth, chart.plotHeight)
        .attr({
        zIndex: 3
    })
        .add();

}
```

});

[See also this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzoon/7x51pdg3/5/)

I noticed that the image blocks the tooltips of the chart. I guess that was to be expected because the image is above the chart by purpose.

Can anyone think of a way to show chart tooltips in the transparent parts of the image?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474375/highcharts-tooltip-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show tooltip only through transparent parts of the custom image you would need to increase `zIndex` of the custom image through `zIndex` attr.

To enable mouse tracking for chart, so tooltip could be triggered through mouse events over plot area you could set `'pointer-events': 'none'` for the image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7x51pdg3/6/

If you are not satisfied with position of tooltip you can control it via [tooltip.positioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner).

Comment: Thanks! By the way: I found out that if I don't increase zIndex, but only add 'pointer-events': 'none', the tooltips get rendered above the image. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/kzoon/7x51pdg3/7/